# How to remove all non numeric characters from a python 3 list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Someone can help me :

from this python3 list :

```
['{', ' "100": {', ' "AT": {', ' "av": -64.519, ', ' "ct": 17754, ', ' "mn": -96.023, ', ' "mx": -14.294', ' }, ', ' "First_UTC": "2019-03-08T23:09:35Z", ']
```

I need to make this list :

```
[100,-64.519,17754,-96.023,14.294,2019-03-08T23:09:35Z]
```

Comment: Looks to me a strange list of dictionaries.

Comment: yeah dude you need to go back to the source and get the data in correctly. this looks messed up

Comment: It seems you split a string dictionary

Comment: It's a list that I create from a json file. This is not the problem here. It's a list like any lists. I just need now to keed only the numers.

Comment: FWIW, `-,.,:,T,Z` are not considered integers either, yet you show them in your desired output.

Comment: Why are you treating the input as a list if you have a JSON file?

Comment: @hamdy.aea this is not the problem you see, but this is definitely the problem you have. What are you trying to do? Give us the bigger picture so we can really help.

Comment: can you please either give the file from which you have created this or explain why you cannot ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the closest what you need. Convert the values to `float` where possible and convert rest of the values to `datetime` objects

```
import re
import datetime
res=[]
a=['{', ' "100": {', ' "AT": {', ' "av": -64.519, ', ' "ct": 17754, ', ' "mn": -96.023, ', ' "mx": -14.294', ' }, ', ' "First_UTC": "2019-03-08T23:09:35Z", '] 
for i in a:
    m=re.search('([-]?\d{1,}[.\d]?[\w:-]*)',i)
    if m:
        try:
            tmp = float(m.group(0))
        except:
            tmp = datetime.datetime.strptime(m.group(0), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        res.append(tmp)
```

**Output**

```
[100.0,
 -64.519,
 17754.0,
 -96.023,
 -14.294,
 datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 8, 23, 9, 35)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your input:

```
l=['{', ' "100": {', ' "AT": {', ' "av": -64.519, ', ' "ct": 17754, ', ' "mn": -96.023, ', ' "mx": -14.294', ' }, ', ' "First_UTC": "2019-03-08T23:09:35Z", ']
_
```

in two steps:

```
l1= [re.sub("[^0-9-]", "", x) for x in l]
```

Now, you can remove empty literals and get it all as string.

```
l2=[x for x in l1 if x!=""]
```

You can also translate to int, except the last because "2019-03-08T23:09:35Z" is not a valid literal

```
l3 = [int(x) for x in l2[:-1]]

print(l3)
[100, -64519, 17754, -96023, -14294]
```

Comment: But it removed the . and I need it -64.519 is not 64519

Comment: So the best solution is : l1= [re.sub("[^0-9-.]", "", x) for x in data]
l2= [x for x in l1 if x!=""]
l3 = [float(x) for x in l2[:-1]]